# use span or input element for not editable form field

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I just started with [twitter bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms).

I want to create a disabled form field. In the documention I found this snippet:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Disabled input here..." disabled>
```

But in IE9 the placeholder doesn' work. When I use the `value` attribute to set the content it  works (and overwrite the palceholder text, which worked in other browsers like chrome).

There is an alternative way without using the input element:

```
<span class="uneditable-input">Some value here</span>
```

This also works in IE9 and chrome. Which solution is better (compatible with old browsers, like IE8, 7 (and 6) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE 7/8/9 doesn't support the HTML5 placeholder. The best solution must be to use a script/plugin that provide the functionality (*when it does not exist*)

See https://github.com/miketaylr/jQuery-html5-placeholder

I also have had great experiences with http://jquery-watermark.googlecode.com/

They both use the HTML5 if it is available, and emulate it if it's not.

They are incredible simple to use. To use watermark for instance, just include it and add a line to your document.ready()

```
$("#my-input").watermark('default text');
```

Answer (score 4):

I found out, when I want to use the `Prepended and appended inputs` of [twitter bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms)
I must use the input element. It doesn't work with the span element.

Example:

```
<div class="input-prepend">
  <span class="add-on">@</span>
  <input class="span2" id="prependedInput" type="text" placeholder="Username">
</div>

<div class="input-append">
  <input class="span2" id="appendedInput" type="text">
  <span class="add-on">.00</span>
</div>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

```
<span class="uneditable-input">Some value here</span>
```

is better imho..

Reason- it will act as expected in new and old browsers and it doesn't depend on any external script but only css style `uneditable-input`

When you can simply echo your value in a `span` tag than why to use a disabled form field..??

Answer (score 2):

The `placeholder` attribute is HTML5 and does not work in many browsers, especially older ones, which is why it doesn't work in IE9. (Microsoft doesn't follow standards even in IE9.)

If your question is if a span would be more compatible than the `placeholder` attribute, then yes it is. A span should be supported by all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You could go with the javascript alternative...

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Disabled input here..." onfocus="this.blur()" />
```